# Insert content Dynamically into URL generated by user through PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Aim: To allow a User to create a URL through an Input Field and Dynamically Add something onto the page that specific URL parameter leads to

example:  User Enters word "box" into the field, the input "box" is stored in database and a custom URL having the "box" parameter is generated, I wish to put some content onto that URL and the URL should only display the input.

Result: "localhost/3/UrlGeneration.php?url=Box"
Expected: "localhost/3/Box"

(PS: Maybe I am doing this wrong and should create individual files for each input but that would result in A LOT OF FILLLLLEEEES which held me back from doing that)

```
<form action="UrlGeneration.php" method="GET">
 <input type="text" name="url" size="25" placeholder="Enter Custom URL">
 <button type="submit">Launch</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php

include('Includes/php/Connect.php');

$URL = $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']);
$Time = $conn->real_escape_string($_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO url (room, tstamp) VALUES ('$URL', '$Time')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$url = "http://localhost/UrlGeneration.php?$URL";
header($url);


// Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: You're looking for something to do with your webserver. For instance, if you're using Apache you would try to [rewrite the URL](https://aloneonahill.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners).

Comment: I would recommend looking into using a PHP router (there are many to choose from if you search for it). Then it's easy to set up URL's with dynamic values.